# Core Data Recipes Question

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity, iphonecoredatarecipes

This is just a quick question I have about Apple's core data "Recipes" project, so I don't need elaborate answers.  When you edit a recipe you can also edit the type.  When the type cell is pressed it presents the user with a table view populated by multiple types.  How exactly were those types created?  I can't seem to find an explanation in the project code or in the .xcdatamodel (I've checked everywhere, and searched it)  Also, why does "RecipeType" have to be it's own entity? Why can't it just be part of the "Recipe" entity?  Does that have anything do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `RecipeType` doesn't necessarily have to be its own type, but it is common practice. Using an association like this has many benefits. Say if you wanted to add more metadata per type, you could add it to the `RecipeType` instead of duplicating a bunch of data throughout your recipes.

It appears that these recipe types are already inserted into the SQLite database `Recipes.sqlite`. It doesn't appear that they used any of the code in the project to populate this database. It was most likely done using Terminal or some other GUI SQLite editor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it helped a lot.  However, is there an easy way to insert those items through objective-c code? I have no intent of learning SQLite, and I want to keep it that way.

Comment: You could, there are various other sample code projects that do this. Although, it would really be a lot easier to just interact with the SQLite database via Terminal or a GUI app like the [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/). You won't really have to learn much SQL if you use the GUI interface.